# "Could not find action or result" in Struts

Tags: struts

I'm currently creating a web application using the jquery+struts plugin. It also uses hibernate. I have two web pages already, the other one works perfectly fine but when I created another one, it threw an error saying that the action cannot be found. The error is:

```
ERROR (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:38) - Could not find action or result
/mims_agchem/index.action
No result defined for action com.agchem.mims.actions.Index and result success
```

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:375)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
 at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)

These are my codes:

struts.xml

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="hibernate-default,json-default,struts-default">
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="showcaseStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>
  <default-interceptor-ref name="showcaseStack"/>
  <action name="*" class="com.agchem.mims.actions.admin.{1}">
    <result>/jsp/admin/{1}.jsp</result>
    <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
  </action>
</package>
<package name="general" namespace="/" extends="hibernate-default,json-default,struts-default">
  <interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="showcaseStack">
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>
  <action name="index" class="com.agchem.mims.actions.Index">
    <result name="success">/jsp/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Index.java

```
package com.agchem.mims.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Index extends ActionSupport {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1475579903320095412L;

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AGCHEM MIMS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="struts2,jquery, hibernate, plugin,showcase, grid" />
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="Project Maintenance" />
    <link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <sj:head
  loadAtOnce="true"
  compressed="false"
  jquerytheme="mims"
  customBasepath="../themes"
  loadFromGoogle="false"
  debug="true"
/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <s:url id="adm201" action="ADM201"/>
  <s:url id="adm210" action="ADM210"/>
  <s:url id="adm301" action="ADM301"/>
  <s:url id="adm310" action="ADM310"/>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu" style="width: 765px">
      <li>
        <sj:a href="../general/main_admin.html" targets="main">Home</sj:a>
      </li>
      <li class="current">
        <sj:a href="#" class="parent">Project</sj:a>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><sj:a href="%{adm201}" class="current" targets="main">Create New Project</sj:a></li>
              <li><sj:a href="%{adm210}" targets="main">Search Projects</sj:a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <sj:a href="#" class="parent">User</sj:a>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><sj:a href="%{adm301}" targets="main">Create New User</sj:a></li>
              <li><sj:a href="%{adm310}" targets="main">Search Users</sj:a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <sj:div id="main" href="%{adm201}">
    <img id="indicator" src="../images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
  </sj:div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone could explain and help me on my problem. Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Honey =)

Comment: sorry for the wrong format in the error section..

Answer (score 0):

The other page already worked. With just some refresh and restarts on the server, the page just worked fine. :) Weird though.. :)